# sbt-dependency-graph equivalent for inter-project dependencies

Tags: sbt

Is there's a `sbt-dependency-graph` equivalent for inter-project dependencies (ie. `projectA dependsOn projectB`)? Either as an sbt plugin or using sbt internals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't know of a plugin to do what you need.

Here is a simple SBT task to quickly show all the dependencies in the project. This is really basic, I am sure we can do something better in the visualization/formatting of the output. Add the following in your `build.sbt` file.

```scala
lazy val showInterProjectDependencies = taskKey[String]("Print inter-project dependencies")

showInterProjectDependencies := {
   val pd: Seq[ModuleID] = projectDependencies.value
   val str = name + " -> " + pd.map(_.name).mkString(", ")
   streams.value.log.info(str)
   str
}
```

If you have a multi-project build, then add this inside your project template:

```scala
def projectTemplate(name: String, dir: String): Project = {
  Project(id = name, base = file(dir)).settings(
    showInterProjectDependencies := {
      val p: Seq[ModuleID] = projectDependencies.value
      val str = name + " -> " + p.map(_.name).mkString(", ")
      streams.value.log.info(str)
      str
    }, 
    ...
}
```

If you have a Root project that aggregates all your subproject then calling `showInterProjectDependencies` will recursively call the task in all the subproject. E.g.:

```scala
lazy val projectRoot = (
  projectTemplate("MyProjectRoot", ".")
  aggregate(subproject1, subproject2, ...) 
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Straight `show projectDependencies` out the box is also reasonably useful. Excellent.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up going ahead and writing one: [sbt-project-graph](https://github.com/dwijnand/sbt-project-graph).